# PENTAHO data integration data source/destination mapping

Tags: mapping, integration, pentaho, etl, data-integration

I'm reaching you hoping to find answers about Pentaho data integrator limitation.
I'm currentlty working on a 1 to 1 data source integration and would like to make it n to 1-n. This requires dynamic jobs creation and would like to know if any of came across  such issue. My 1 to 1 is working perfectly, it integration form differents data source types (CSV, databases "Mysql, Oracle ...) to same date destination and need to make it n to 1-n.

Comment: What is `n to n-1` ?
If I understand, you need to run a transformation/job many times with varying parameters. But I am not sure.
Can you give an example ? Say your `1 to 1` is a simple `CSV Input` to `Table output`.

Comment: I need to perform a data extraction from n data sources (which can be CSV ,DATABESE...) to n data destination (which can be CSV ,DATABESE...)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Metadata Injection Step just for that.

A use case similar to yours is described by Diethard [here](http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2015/10/31/Transformation-Executor-Record-Groups.html).

Because it seams that you have a lot of different source format, it may be a good investment to read the use case of Jens, the author of the step, [here](http://kettle.bleuel.com/2016/04/14/pentaho-6-1-part-2/), which (apart for the automation) is precisely your case.

Comment: Many many thanks  AlainD ! this is really helpfull since it is pretty much exactly what i was looking for. I will work on that and will get back to you. THX again

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK in Pentaho DI, it is not possible to create dynamic transformations for any random data sources. PDI looks for the input columns to be available in the input stream before it loads the data to the target database. For example, if you are using 1 data source (in MySQL) and loading the same to the csv output, the csv output step is expecting the presence of input columns in the data source step (Table input). If you are trying to load any **n** random data sources you need to define input columns/fields for each of them individually.

Alternatively there are few things which you can explore:

**1. Fast Dump in Text File Output step:**

There is an option to **fast data dump** the data set in Text file output step. Here you don't need to define any output column. The input fields will be automatically dumped without formatting as it is. You can use this to map all of the input sources to a csv format and then load it to their targets.

**2. Extending Java and Kettle together to build a solution:**

PDI allows you to create custom JAVA codes on top of kettle. You can check [this blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/java-and-pentaho-kettle-executing-a-kettle-file-using-java/) for more. You can use this idea to create custom code to pass n data sources fields to the kettle as a parameter and execute them. {note: i haven't tried this step, just thinking out loud here}

Hope this helps :)